# Dismissing a ViewController does not get to desired Controller

Tags: ios, interface-builder, ecslidingviewcontroller

I am terrible at understanding work with interface builder, so (probably dumb)  question comes.
I have created sliding view controller. When I click a cell, I want this controller slide back as it was. I used `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];`. 
It used to dismiss table view controller (when I did not use Sliding). However, not it throws me not to previous controller, but to login page (initial controller). Have a look at the picture.[image]

Hope this provides enough information. Sorry if it is not enough, as I am really bad with interface builder. I will add anything needed as requested. Thank you.

EDIT:
I have also tried to drag (holding ctrl) from sliding controller and chose ECSlidingSegue. In such case there is nothing going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal behavior of modal is when dismissed it shows its `Parent Controller`, in your case its I guess `LoginViewController`, form where you must have presented the `TableViewController` as modal.

However, if you wish to show a different controller other than the Parent, you can choose to push a new controller when come from TableViewController, or, you can achieve modal appearance with simple push of navigation controller, and I guess this would be easier and correct in your case.

So instead of presenting the TableViewController as modal, push it with Modal animation, and on selection of cell `InboxViewController` will be pushed.

There are few changes you need to do.

1. Create a `Custom Segue` from `LoginController` to `TableViewController`.
2. Create a `push segue` from `TableViewController` to `InboxViewController`.

I hope it helps.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi, I have tried till now, but it does not work for me (. I think I am doing something wrong. As I said, I don't really understand IB. Is there a way to explain it a bit more detailed? I really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to create Custom Segue, for the custom push animation, for help look here http://jrwren.wrenfam.com/blog/2012/02/01/storyboard-custom-segue-for-custom-pushviewcontroller-animation/

Comment: Yes, I have created custom segue right now. I can go to InboxViewController, but when I press "Menu" button, not the app crashes and gives error something like EXC_BAD_ACCESS (...).

Comment: And the sliding view does not open coz of the crash.